# what is the meaning of "?" and "!" in Ruby

Tags: ruby, naming-conventions

I am seeing this type code in Ruby often but I don't understand it.
I am talking about the "?" and "!" character.  For the examples below,
are they being used as just part of the function name or is it some kind of operators ?

```
unless n.is_a? Integer

prime_array = [] if prime_array.nil?

myarray.sort!
```

Comment: Ok thank you Meagar and Marek.  My head is clear :)

Comment: Don't forget to mark one of answers (preferably meagar's one, since it's much more comprehensive than mine) as accepted.

Comment: I guess that they down voted you because this topic is easy. Well, without knowing proper names for `!` - exclamation marks (or in Ruby's case: *bang methods*) and `?` question mark, google won't help you. Well, you can find some names in the English wiki. And I've looked up at few posts and I've found Matz' post: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/176830#773946

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby's syntax allows you to postfix a single `?` or `!` to your method names (both or more than one of each is invalid).

This is to support a couple of deeply ingrained conventions:

#### `method?`:

A method that returns a boolean and doesn't modify its receiver's state should use a `?`. For example, if you want to "ask" whether a container is sorted, you might use `my_obj.sorted?`. If you want to "ask" whether a container is empty, you might use `my_obj.empty?`. Neither of these methods would modify their receiving object's state. See [`String`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html) for many examples of `?` methods being used to interrogate an object without modifying it, such as `start_with?` and `end_with?`.

#### `method!`:

A method that has a `!` at the end destructively modifies its objects state. By extension, when a method might destructively transform an object's state, there are often two versions of the method provided, with and without a `!`. In the case of an array, you might have a pair of methods called `sort` and `sort!`. `sort` will return a copy of the array, in sorted order, without modifying the original copy. After calling `sort`, you will have two copies, including an unmodified version of the original. `sort!` however, will sort the array in-place, overwriting the original array.

Again, referring to [`String`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html), we have methods such as `capitalize` which returns a capitalized copy of a string, and `capitalize!` which capitalizes the string in-place:

```
x = "what"
y = x.capitalize
puts x # "what"; x is unchanged
puts y # "What"

x = "what"
y = x.capitalize!
puts x # "What"; x is changed in-place
puts y # "What"
```

It's worth noting that Rails has its own conventions for the semantics of `!`. In Rails, a method that can fail (such as a database write) will typically return `true` or `false`. Rails uses a `!` to indicate that the method should fail with an exception, instead of a `false` return value. For example, `my_record.save` will return `false` on failure; `my_record.save!` will raise an exception.

Comment: method!: it not just something that will modify the objects state, it is generally used when there are unexpected side effects, not just modifying the caller.

Other examples:
exit! which does not run finalizers like exit does

Comment: I should add to my comment, the rails example in which an exception is thrown instead of "true/false" is another example of an "unexpected" side effect that warrants the ! at the end of a method. 

Think of it as a "warning" that you should check the documentation to see what is special about this method before using it.

Comment: @JeffPrice In my opinion (that what I have read) `!` (bang) suggest that this method is dangerous. I think that modifying the caller, `exit!`, other side effects are *dangerous*

Comment: Well, to be pedantic, Ruby allows method with more than one `?` or `!` (or other letter than a-z, A-Z, 0-9)  `class A;
   define_method 'true?!' do;
     puts 'yes!';
   end;
 end;  a=A.new; a.send 'true?!' # yes!`

Answer (score 2):

These are parts of method names. Ruby convention is that methods returning boolean values are named with `?` on the end, while possibly harmful methods are named with `!`.

Comment: Ok, I understand the "?" now.  I am still not sure about the "!" though.  I assume that the "!" does not stand for the NOT operator.  Are you saying that if method has the "!" by convention means that it can do something harmful ?

Comment: "! methods" often mutate the object they are called on.

Comment: I'm saying that if method has `!` on the end means by convention that it can do something harmful. But `!` is also operator, if you put it in front of some expression, it will return its negation:
`!false #=> true `.